# limiting only value 0/1 in <td> html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to limit only 0 or 1 in  tag.

```
<td contenteditable id='test'>
#input 0/1
</td>
```

Any ideas on how to do this using js or css?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/f8sug/5/) demo 
An update, since .live() is deprecated please use `.on` instead of `.live`

```
$("td input").on("keypress",function(){

 var alpha = new Array();
        alpha = [ "0","1"];
        var charpressed = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if(this.value.length>=1){
    return false;
    }
        if (!($.inArray(charpressed, alpha) > -1)) {
               return false;
        }
    else
    {
    $("#required").html('');
    }


});
```

Refer the updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/f8sug/4/)

Comment: what about 000 and 111??

Comment: tks 
like Yashhly said, I just want 0/1.

Comment: if you want to restrict the character length you can do it by checking its length and do it 
refer this fiddle

Comment: @user3054044   oh Okay I have updated it in the answer! Sorry i thought u wanted to allow only 0 and 1

Comment: tks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

you may use this as well

```
$("#test").keypress(function (e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == 48 || e.keycode == 49) {
        alert("true");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("false");
        return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this is to check against the innerHTML value of the td. An example of this would be:

```
var myTD = document.getElementById('test');
if( myTD.innerHTML != '1' || myTD.innerHTML != '0' ) {
    myTD.innerHTML = '';
    alert("Incorrect value.");
}
```

This really depends on where you're getting the data for the TD, though.

For a contenteditable TD you can use the "DOMCharacterDataModified" event listener.